"0" is an invalid render array key. Value should be an array but got a string. in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children()
When upgrading from 9.5 to 10.3, rendering the home page returns the error below.
I've tried searching for the cause, but can't find it. The stacktrace mentions the theme, both the theme and maintenance theme i'm using are set in core.extensions theme. I've tried googling but the links I find seem to have slightly different issues and causes.
Any pointer would help greatly:).
InvalidArgumentException: "0" is an invalid render array key. Value should be an array but got a string. in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (Line: 248)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render() (Line: 476)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (Line: 65)
__TwigTemplate_5a57f8db7ac7ab73ebef615a50c49577->doDisplay() (Line: 393)
Twig\Template->yield() (Line: 349)
Twig\Template->display() (Line: 364)
Twig\Template->render() (Line: 35)
Twig\TemplateWrapper->render() (Line: 33)
twig_render_template() (Line: 348)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render() (Line: 491)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (Line: 248)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render() (Line: 476)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (Line: 329)
__TwigTemplate_1c10b7b5f11c822ef981cbc9e3007a19->doDisplay() (Line: 393)
Twig\Template->yield() (Line: 349)
Twig\Template->display() (Line: 364)
Twig\Template->render() (Line: 35)
Twig\TemplateWrapper->render() (Line: 33)
twig_render_template() (Line: 348)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render() (Line: 491)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (Line: 248)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render() (Line: 476)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (Line: 93)
__TwigTemplate_fdef4cbc091a25172c88e397d4f1ee92->doDisplay() (Line: 393)
Twig\Template->yield() (Line: 349)
Twig\Template->display() (Line: 364)
Twig\Template->render() (Line: 35)
Twig\TemplateWrapper->render() (Line: 33)
twig_render_template() (Line: 348)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render() (Line: 491)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (Line: 248)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render() (Line: 158)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 638)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 153)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse() (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray()
call_user_func() (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch() (Line: 186)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 76)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 53)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 28)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle() (Line: 32)
Drupal\big_pipe\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle() (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 36)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\AjaxPageState->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 741)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)


Comment No. 17 resolved this issue for me. It should fix it for you as well.  Apply it to drupal/core
https://www.drupal.org/project/skeletontheme/issues/3275683#comment-15652299

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
